# Lévy metric implementation

Tags: r, statistics, metric

I would like to implement (in R) the evaluation of the Lévy distance between two curves.
Given two cumulative distributions, the formal definition is the following (see also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_metric)):

[image: img]

Essentially one is trying to find the largest square that can be drawed between the two curves.
I am dealing with two cumulatives which are step functions with same domain, so the implementation should be easier than the general case.
Thanks in advance.

Is there any library that implements this metric, or something similar.
If not, could you suggest some hints to start from scratch?

Comment: Is there a question here? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: What Roman said.   For example, can you program `inf(x)` , or the CDFs themselves?

Comment: I edited the question, in order to be more clear, thanks.